# Errors  when installing Mysql Server 5.1

Tags: 11.10, mysql

I'm trying to install mysql server,and I'm getting the following error.

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1`

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

Suggested packages:

  tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:

  mysql-server-5.1

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Need to get 0 B/6,259 kB of archives.

After this operation, 13.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.

Preconfiguring packages ...

Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server-5.1.

(Reading database ... 158432 files and directories currently installed.)

Unpacking mysql-server-5.1 (from .../mysql-server-5.1_5.1.62-0ubuntu0.11.10.1_i386.deb) 
...

Processing triggers for man-db ...

Processing triggers for ureadahead ...

Setting up mysql-server-5.1 (5.1.62-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...

120427 19:04:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

120427 19:04:07  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M

120427 19:04:07  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

120427 19:04:07  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233

120427 19:04:07  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...

120427 19:04:13  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233

start: Job failed to start

invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.1 (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.1

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can i install `mysql-server`? Someone pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo mv /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.bak; sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1 mysql-client-5.1
```

Comment: same error again :(